# Sync SQL Server Express (client db) with SQL Server 2008 (server) using WCF web services - MS Sync Framework

Tags: sql-server, wcf, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I am looking to develop an application for windows laptops to work with or without internet connection. I was looking at MS Sync, which very much provides the solution. I have SQL Server 2008 at my server. I can have SQL Server CE or SQL Server Express on client. SQL Server Express gives me an advantage of using stored procs etc. while SQL CE is lot less powerful. Since my server db is hosted at a public server I do not want to expose it directly to the application. So I was looking to do the synchronization using WCF web services. But I am unable to find client sync provider for the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can find samples here for using Sync Framework with WCF.

[Database Sync: SQL Server and SQL Compact N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-Sync-SQL-Server-7e88adab)

[Database Sync:SQL Server and SQL Express N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208)

you might have to tweak the samples though because the client application directly references the service assembly.